# XSLT Adding in a for-each loop

Tags: xslt

Is there a way to create a for-each loop in XSLT that will add in the value of each node it loops through?

For Example, is there a way to create a loop to add together the price nodes to get a total price?

```
<cd>
    <title>Hide your heart</title>
    <artist>Bonnie Tyler</artist>
    <country>UK</country>
    <company>CBS Records</company>
    <price>9.90</price>
    <year>1988</year>
</cd>
<cd>
    <title>Greatest Hits</title>
    <artist>Dolly Parton</artist>
    <country>USA</country>
    <company>RCA</company>
    <price>9.90</price>
    <year>1982</year>
</cd>
<cd>
    <title>Still got the blues</title>
    <artist>Gary Moore</artist>
    <country>UK</country>
    <company>Virgin records</company>
    <price>10.20</price>
    <year>1990</year>
</cd>
```

Here is the current code I am trying to use to extract the price and hold it as a variable:

```
<xsl:template name="Amount-Calc">
    <xsl:value-of select="sum(//cd[country = 'UK'])"/>>
    <xsl:variable name="FullPrice" select="price" />
    <xsl:variable name="dollars" select="substring($FullPrice,1,2)" />
    <xsl:variable name="cents" select="substring($FullPrice,3,2)" />
</xsl:template>
```

I am not sure how to store the full price as a variable

My Expected output is:

```
<price=20.10/>
```

However when I do my calculation I am getting `<price=NaN/>`

Comment: **1.** Your input is not valid XML. **2.** Your template is out of context. **3.** It contains a double `>>`. **4.** You are not summing the `price`. **5.** Your output is not valid XML.

Comment: Is your question not answered?

Comment: I have since gone with a different method. this did not work in the way I would like.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a way to create a for-each loop in XSLT that will add in the
>   value of each node it loops through?

It is neither possible, nor necessary.

- It's not possible, because `xsl:for-each` is not a loop.
- It's not necessary, because you can sum the nodes using an expression like `sum(cd/price)`from the context of the parent node (missing from your example).

---

### Added:

Given a **well-formed** XML input:

```
<root>
    <cd>
        <title>Hide your heart</title>
        <artist>Bonnie Tyler</artist>
        <country>UK</country>
        <company>CBS Records</company>
        <price>9.90</price>
        <year>1988</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Greatest Hits</title>
        <artist>Dolly Parton</artist>
        <country>USA</country>
        <company>RCA</company>
        <price>9.90</price>
        <year>1982</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Still got the blues</title>
        <artist>Gary Moore</artist>
        <country>UK</country>
        <company>Virgin records</company>
        <price>10.20</price>
        <year>1990</year>
    </cd>
</root>
```

the following stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <total-price>
        <xsl:value-of select="format-number(sum(cd[country = 'UK']/price), '0.00')"/>
    </total-price>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

will return:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<total-price>20.10</total-price>
```

Comment: are you able to make a variable with the sum?

Comment: Yes. Post a complete example, with a valid input and the expected output.

Comment: I am getting a NaN value I believe because there is a . in the price value

Comment: I cannot help you when you don't post a valid XML input and the expected output. "*I am getting a NaN value I believe because there is a . in the price value*" No, that's not the reason.

Comment: expected out put is just the sum of the price when country = UK